# Can I run a single Mac application inside a virtual machine?

Tags: mac, virtual-machine

How can I run a single Mac app inside a virtual machine without installing Mac OS X?

Answer (score 5):

You can't. You simply cannot run just a Mac app in a VM without installing OS X. Installing OS X in a VM is also against the [Mac OS X Software License Agreement](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macosx106.pdf) where it is stated:

> "you are granted a limited non-exclusive license to install, use and run one (1) copy of the Apple Software on a *single Apple-branded computer* at a time.

Which rules out VMs. You could of course try to find a cross-platform alternative and use that.

Comment: He never actually said he was on a non-Apple branded computer. You can install Windows as the base OS on an Intel based Apple box.

Comment: @Fambida: Obviously you can install Windows. But you can't install OS X on VMs

Answer (score 3):

You almost certainly need the operating system installed for your application to work.  It has to make at least some kind of system calls to do even the most basic I/O, let alone all the layers of frameworks and system services required to make a GUI app function.

Answer (score 1):

No.

However, you might want to look into OS X's support for application sandboxing:
http://techjournal.318.com/security/a-brief-introduction-to-mac-os-x-sandbox-technology/